# how to make alarm notification On just Friday every week in android

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I am working on an application in which i want to make a notification on Friday every week i have tried this code but it make notification on every day

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,6);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        String h = String.valueOf(hourOfDay);
        String m = String.valueOf(minute);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), notification.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),  7*AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(Settings.this, h+ " : " + m , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Notification.class

```
  public class notification extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,new Intent(context,The_main.class),0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.awq)
            .setContentTitle("remainder")
            .setContentText(" time to read");
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   notificationManager.cancel(1);
    notificationManager.notify(1,builder.build());
       }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
 `7*AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY`
```

with

```
7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 (7days Interval in milliseconds)
```

Comment: Post the full code including Notification.class as well